# Compatibility Between PyPubSub and PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pypubsub

I have been trying to find the most elegant way to decouple my programs from the GUI, such that I can change my front-end without needing to re-write a whole lot of code.

I work with threads a lot, so I often have the need to notify the main GUI thread of asynchronous happenings either through *events* (for wxPython) or *signals* (for PyQt). I have experimented a bit with [PyPubSub](https://pypubsub.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.0/), which may be what I am looking for, but while there are tons of wxPython examples (since it was originally included with it in early development).

I am not aware if there is a 'proper' way to use it with PyQt without running into race conditions. If anyone has some insight on this, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.aizac.info/the-easiest-way-of-inter-thread-communication-for-python/) example in PyQt4

Comment: The example referenced by @avram is unfortunately not thread safe and may lead GUI to crash, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

PyPubSub's sendMessage() will call listeners in the same thread as the sender (default Python behavior). In a multithreaded GUI app, you must ensure that listeners that interact with GUI are called in the main thread. Also threads execute independently, so you need each thread to call its own listeners, based on a timed or idle callback mechanism.

The way to call listeners in the correct thread in PyQt is via signals. PyPubSub can still be used in a multithreaded PyQt GUI, but the mechanism used to transfer the "message" from sender to listener would have to be via a signal. There isn't one best way to do it I don't think, depends on details of your app design. You could for example have a `QtPubsubHandler` that derives from `QObject` and gets created in main thread, and a `QtPubsubSender` class that also derives from `QObject` and gets created in each worker thread. The `QtPubSubSender` defines a custom signal, say `pubsub`, which `QtPubsubHandler` connects to. Then to send a message, the sender does `qtPubsubHandler.sendMessage(topic, **data)`, which causes a `pubsub` signal to get emitted, which Qt properly queues and eventually signals the `QtPubsubHandler`, which actually calls `pub.sendMessage()`.

There are many other ways, but you get the general idea: two classes that derive from QObject, and one of them does the actual sending in the same thread as the intended listener, the other uses a signal so everything is thread safe. Actually you don't have to use PyQt signals: but then you would have to have a queue in main thread and have an idle callback that allows it to process any items on the queue.